# issue with setScopes function in google/client.php

Tags: php

```
 /**
   * This function allows you to overrule the automatically generated scopes,
   * so that you can ask for more or less permission in the auth flow
   * Set this before you call authenticate() though!
   * @param array $scopes, ie: array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/moderator')
   */
  public function setScopes($scopes) {
    $this->scopes = is_string($scopes) ? explode(" ", $scopes) : $scopes;
  }
```

Above code is from google/Client.php,

Questions:

1. in comments, what does this mean: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me`?
2. If i donot setScopes, what is the default scope?

Answer (score 0):

> in comments, what does this mean: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me?

That scope is specific to the user making the call and says get me all the generic google plus information (name profile picture etc.).

> If i do not setScopes, what is the default scope?

No default scope, it will throw an error if you fail to specify.